# what is the difference between GKE and EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I am learning clouds like AWS and GCP, in which I came across two products called GKE and EKS.

Can anybody let me know the difference? Please also suggest which would be the best option to go with for the beginners as am new to cloud

Comment: You may want to remove the part that asks for a suggestion, since that's explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Ask Gemini on it, I'm pretty sure the comparison is fair. Keep in mind that Google is the main commiter of Kubernetes and it runs smoother, better and more efficiently on GCP. EKS took times to come, but AWS is a great integrator of third party solution (because it rarely build its own), and EKS is also a viable solution to use Kubernetes!

Comment: I recommend rethinking your question. Kubernetes is the system (software product). GKE and EKS are implementations of Kubernetes. The primary difference is the management interfaces that GCP and AWS provide. IMHO Google is very committed to the advancement of Kubernetes. AWS simply provides Kubernetes as one of its vast service offerings. For 95% of use cases, either one provides an excellent Kubernetes offering. Search for articles like this one: https://medium.com/@dr.daler.boboev/gke-vs-eks-unraveling-the-key-differences-between-google-kubernetes-engine-and-amazon-elastic-2ab5b8bec20d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your query, it would be better if you could go through the below docs
GKE https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine?hl=en
Eks https://aws.amazon.com/eks/

Comment: Link-only answers are not recommended. Either expand your answer with details or move your answer to a comment on the question. Answers must provide an answer that does not require going to off-site resources.